# Jelastic Tomcat Console.Log Files

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jelastic

How do I access the tomcat console.log files in jelastic?

So that I can see.

```
`System.out.println("I want to see this message");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xxLITxx,

You can find your console.log in catalina.out file.
Also, you can edit conf/logging.properties and change the line:

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Then Tomcat will only log to catalina.log file.

Let us know if you need anything else, Jelastic Support!

Answer (score 2):

File found in the folder
`/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`